# how to create hyperlinks for specific cells in a excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, hyperlink, pywin32

I have a dataframe as given below. I want to insert this dataframe inside the outlook mail and send it in the same format
[dataframe][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE7Zr.png
I want to hyperlink the column "Issue_Ticket" where the value is present. I have tried the following code but I am getting a nonetype error. Can some one help me out with this please?

```
def format_df(dataframe):
    dataframe['Issue_Ticket'] = dataframe['Issue_Ticket'].apply(lambda x: f'<a href="https://jira.net/browse/{x}">{x}</a>')
    dataframe.to_html(justify='center', render_links=True, escape=False, na_rep='NaN')
```

Inside the mail body of outlook, I am calling the following function:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Test_Results.xlsx", sheet_name='data').fillna('-')
html_body = '''\
<html><head></head>
<body>''' + format_df(df) + '''</body></html>
```

**Error:**
html_body = '''
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: i guess you havent use return for your function

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_clickable(url, name):
    url = url + name
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(url,name)

def format_df(dff):
    dff['Issue_Ticket'] = dff.apply(lambda x: make_clickable(base_url, x['Issue_Ticket']), axis=1)
    dff['Issue_Ticket'] = dff.apply(lambda x: '' if x['Issue_Ticket'] == np.NaN else x['Issue_Ticket'],axis=1)
    return dff.to_html(index=False, justify='center', render_links=True, escape=False, na_rep='NaN')
```

Comment: The above logic works